# Is this triangle question missing information?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles

> In the $\Delta KLP$, find $a+b$:
>
> [image: triangle]

My question is that: isn't some information missing from the question? Because all I can see is is that $
\usepackage{ gensymb }

\angle SKP = \angle LTS = p\degree $.

Am I missing some well known formula ??

Please help me with some hints/guides.

Comment: And I notice that the formatting is a bit messed up :( That too even after consulting Detexify. Anyone minds fixing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the triangles $STL$ and $PKL$ are similar, we know the ratios of their sides are the same:

$$\frac{a}{9}=\frac{10}{b+8}=\frac{8}{12}$$

Hence $a=(9)\frac{2}{3}=6$ and $2b+16=30$, hence $b=7$. Finally we have $a+b=13$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are missing the fact that the big triangle and the little triangle are *similar*.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* Please note that $\angle SLT$ is a common angle for $\triangle SLT$ and $\triangle KLP$, and yes, as you noted, the triangles have another pair of equal angles. Now, what do we say about two triangles who have two equal pairs of angles?